# Differences between pyethapp and geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, pyethapp

After using both clients I couldn't find differences in terms of functionality (features) between **geth** and **pyethapp**, only reading that **pyethapp** is more of a stub project that is easily hackable so that its functionality set can be easily expanded.

The **profiles.py** file in **pyetahpp** contains a number of bootstrap nodes to which the client can connect:

```
from os import path


DEFAULT_PROFILE = 'livenet'

genesisdata_dir = path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'genesisdata'))

PROFILES = {
    'livenet': {
        'eth': {
            'network_id': 1,
            'genesis': path.join(genesisdata_dir, 'genesis_frontier.json'),
            'genesis_hash': 'd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3',
        },
        'discovery': {
            'bootstrap_nodes': [
                (  # C++
                    'enode://487611428e6c99a11a9795a6abe7b529e81315ca6aad66e2a2fc76e3adf263fa'
                    'ba0d35466c2f8f68d561dbefa8878d4df5f1f2ddb1fbeab7f42ffb8cd328bd4a'
                    '@5.1.83.226:30303'
                ),
                (  # Go
                    'enode://a979fb575495b8d6db44f750317d0f4622bf4c2aa3365d6af7c284339968eef2'
                    '9b69ad0dce72a4d8db5ebb4968de0e3bec910127f134779fbcb0cb6d3331163c'
                    '@52.16.188.185:30303'
                ),
                (  # Go 2
                    'enode://de471bccee3d042261d52e9bff31458daecc406142b401d4cd848f677479f731'
                    '04b9fdeb090af9583d3391b7f10cb2ba9e26865dd5fca4fcdc0fb1e3b723c786'
                    '@54.94.239.50:30303'
                ),
                (  # Python
                    'enode://2676755dd8477ad3beea32b4e5a144fa10444b70dfa3e05effb0fdfa75683ebd'
                    '4f75709e1f8126cb5317c5a35cae823d503744e790a3a038ae5dd60f51ee9101'
                    '@144.76.62.101:30303'
                )
            ]
        },
    },
    'testnet': {
        'eth': {
            'network_id': 2,
            'genesis': path.join(genesisdata_dir, 'genesis_morden.json'),
            'genesis_hash': '0cd786a2425d16f152c658316c423e6ce1181e15c3295826d7c9904cba9ce303',
            'block': {
                'ACCOUNT_INITIAL_NONCE': 2 ** 20,
                'HOMESTEAD_FORK_BLKNUM': 494000,
            },
        },
        'discovery': {
            'bootstrap_nodes': [
                (   # Go
                    'enode://e4533109cc9bd7604e4ff6c095f7a1d807e15b38e9bfeb05d3b7c423ba86af0'
                    'a9e89abbf40bd9dde4250fef114cd09270fa4e224cbeef8b7bf05a51e8260d6b8'
                    '@94.242.229.4:40404'
                )
            ]
        },
    }
}
```

meaning that there should not be any protocol differences between clients. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> meaning that there should not be any protocol differences between clients. Is this correct?

Yes, both implement the [Ethereum protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper), should be in consensus, and there should be no differences.  In fact, one can earn Ether or Bitcoin
by submitting consensus issues ([examples](http://bounty.ethereum.org/users/jNsSFyEPTSH4ZhraM)) to the [Ethereum Bounty program.](http://bounty.ethereum.org)